# In Xcode->Devices->Console I get keychain entitlement and provisioning profile errors, then my app closes

Tags: provisioning-profile, code-signing-certificate

The instant I open my App it closes again (presumed crashed).  It wasn't attached to my MacBook when it first crashed.  But when I attached it and opened Xcode, I saw this.  Xcode->Devices->View Device Logs has nothing about this issue no matter how many times I repo it.  So I opened the Xcode->Device->Console and it prints something as the app "crashes" (below).

When I attempted to install the debug build I got some complaint from Xcode about either provisioning profiles or certificates or something.  It offered to fix it automatically.  I did that.  I cannot repro the crash anymore on the iPhone in which I reinstalled the debug build.  But that means nothing about my code bugs because my app has state and does various things differently at start-up according to its configuration files.  It went back to the fresh state when I reinstalled the debug build.

So my question is, does this console information below mean that my App is being killed, not because of a code bug crash but because of some keychain or provisioning profile issue?  And if it is the keychain and providing profile issue, are my customer installs suffering from the same "crash"?

I'm not 100% certain but I believe these were ad-hoc installs that I thought used the same signing certificates and provisioning profiles as my iTunes export.

```
Aug 15 12:17:51 iPhone-5-GSM SpringBoard[48] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Aug 15 12:17:51 iPhone-5-GSM SpringBoard[48] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Aug 15 12:17:51 iPhone-5-GSM SpringBoard[48] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Aug 15 12:17:51 iPhone-5-GSM securityd[94] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Aug 15 12:17:51 iPhone-5-GSM securityd[94] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Aug 15 12:17:51 iPhone-5-GSM amfid[195] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Aug 15 12:17:51 iPhone-5-GSM securityd[94] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Aug 15 12:17:51 iPhone-5-GSM securityd[94] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Aug 15 12:17:51 iPhone-5-GSM amfid[195] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Aug 15 12:17:51 iPhone-5-GSM amfid[195] <Error>: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/00000000-0000-0000-0000-03B9C01C0000/MyApp.app/MyApp not valid: 0xe8008015: A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.
Aug 15 12:17:51 iPhone-5-GSM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.MyCompany.MyApp[0xe6e9][249]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9
Aug 15 12:17:51 iPhone-5-GSM assertiond[65] <Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 249: (os/kern) failure (5)
Aug 15 12:17:51 iPhone-5-GSM SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: Unable to register for exec notifications: No such process
Aug 15 12:17:51 iPhone-5-GSM SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 249: (os/kern) failure (5)
Aug 15 12:17:51 iPhone-5-GSM SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x1a58f5c0; com.MyCompany.MyApp; pid: 249>
Aug 15 12:17:51 iPhone-5-GSM SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.MyCompany.MyApp[0xe6e9]' exited abnormally via signal.
Aug 15 12:17:51 iPhone-5-GSM SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: Application '(null)' exited for an unknown reason.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, iOS is stating that your app is not allowed to run on that device because there is not a valid iOS provisioning profile that matches the app and the device.

When you ask about your customers, how did you deploy the app to them?  If they got your app through the Apple App Store, they will not have this problem.  That app was signed with a Distribution profile that will continue to work even when your development and ad hoc profiles expire. You cannot install an app that has been signed with your app store distribution profile, so you must have signed them differently.

If you sent the same ad hoc builds to customers for testing, they would be seeing the same problem.  In order to fix it, you'll need to re-build the app using a new, valid ad hoc provisioning profile, and re-install it on any devices that you need the app to run on.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment.  I was off for a few days hence the late reply.  My question states "I'm not 100% certain but I believe these were ad-hoc installs that I thought used the same signing certificates and provisioning profiles as my iTunes export."  By this I mean that my customers get the App from the App store after I export it to iTunes Connect.  But I had forced the provisioning profile to be the same for release and distribution builds.  I fear that that means that both my ad-hoc builds and my iTunes Connect exports use the same provisioning profile.

Comment: No, if you used an ad hoc build to submit to the app store, it would have gotten rejected.  Apple verifies the code signing when you submit them a binary. You should be OK for your customers.